# Using Age function of postgresql through PHP

Tags: php, postgresql

I am trying to filter my results through Age range. In my db, I have a table which has a column 'dob', so I am trying to use AGE function of postgreSql to get the age from 'dob'. But it's not working. Following is my code.

**contact.php**

```
<div class="form-group">
    <label> Filter by Age</label>
    <div class="input-group">
        <input id="start-age" type="text" name="from-age" class="form-control" placeholder="from" />
        <input id="end-age" type="text" name="to-age" class="form-control" placeholder="to" />
    </div>
</div>

<script>
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $('body').on('change', '#end-age', function () {
            var from_age = $('#start-age').val();
            var to_age = $(this).val();

            var queryString1;
            var queryString2;
            if(location.search && from_age != -1 && to_age != -1){
                queryString1 = getQueryObj(location.search);
                queryString2 = getQueryObj(location.search);
                $.each(queryString1,function(i,e){
                    queryString1[i] = decodeURIComponent(e);
                });
                $.each(queryString2,function(i,e){
                    queryString2[i] = decodeURIComponent(e);
                });
                queryString1.from_filter = from_age;
                queryString2.to_filter = to_age;

            } else if(from_age == -1 && to_age == -1){
                queryString1 = getQueryObj(location.search);
                queryString2 = getQueryObj(location.search);
                delete queryString1.from_filter;
                delete queryString2.to_filter;
            } else {
                queryString1 = {from_filter:from_age};
                queryString2 = {to_filter:to_age};
            }
            window.location.replace('/user?'+ $.param(queryString1) + '&' + $.param(queryString2));
        });
    });

</script>
```

**contactController.php**

```
<?php
class userController extends AdminController {

    function __construct(){
        parent::__construct("Contact","contacts");
    }

    function index(Array $params = []){

        $ageSql = "";
        if(isset($_GET['from_filter']) && isset($_GET['to_filter'])) {
            $from_age = $_GET['from_filter'];
            $to_age = $_GET['to_filter'];
            $ageSql = "SELECT id FROM user WHERE AGE(timestamp dob) >= $from_age AND AGE(timestamp dob) <= ($to_age)";
            $params['queryOptions']['where'][] = "contact_id = $ageSql";

        }
        parent::index($params);
    }
}
```

When I tried the above sql into Postgre, I am getting an error that Age is not a function defined. I want all the users in the range of the age user selects in the filter bar. Help is appreciated. TIA

Comment: age calclulate the difference between the timestamps of two dates. You are missing the second operator for each age

Comment: @LelioFaieta In the postgreSql documentation, it says that if we want to take current date as first argument, we can use the above syntax.

Comment: I tried following query to run on db,
`SELECT id FROM user WHERE AGE(timestamp dob) >= 20 AND AGE(timestamp dob) <= (30);`

I got an Error: syntax error at or near "birthdate"

Comment: Try removing the `timestamp` in front of `dob`. I expect that `dob` is a `date`, right? If not cast it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to use `now()` instead of `timestamp`. Also if you want to compare only years use `EXTRACT YEAR form AGE()`, which will give you only year. 
Assuming your dob is of date or timestamp type:

```
$ageSql = "SELECT id FROM table WHERE EXTRACT(YEAR FROM AGE(now(), dob)) >= 25 AND EXTRACT(YEAR FROM AGE(now(), dob)) <= 40";
$params['queryOptions']['where'][] = "contact_id IN $ageSql"; //use 'IN' in case more than 1 row
```

And if 'dob' is of some varchar or text type, cast it like this- `dob::timestamp`